# Solving For Maxflow with unknown edge capacities using Ford-Fulkerson

Tags: analysis

I am having difficulty on how to proceed with the next step for a flow network problem. The link to the assignment is http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring11/cos226/exercises/64MaxFlow.html. I have already completed the graph, but am having trouble understanding how to proceed with the second question. I know as far as flow goes in a flow network that the flow must be greater than/equal to 0 or less than/equal to the capacity, and the inflow and outflow of a vertex must be equal. However, I am stumped as how to solve the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm, due to lack of capacity for the edges in the middle of the graph. Any opinions are greatly appreciated. (I'm pretty certain it goes against the rules to post questions pertaining to homework assignments on this board, but I am truly stumped, and have not received much feedback from fellow students on the discussion board for the class, so any small nudge or push in the right direction is immensely appreciated!) [Blood Supply Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wdeet.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Fun problem! I just completed my own algorithms course, so here is my advice:

Are you familiar with the bipartite matching problem? It is the problem of finding a subset of edges in the graph such that each vertex in the graph appears in at most one edge in the matching. An extension of this problem is to find a perfect matching in a bipartite graph — that is, a matching that includes all the vertices in the graph.

There is a very interesting network flow construction that finds a perfect matching in a bipartite graph, and the critical point (just as it is for you) is what capacities we assign those middle edges.

You should look into the perfect matching algorithm to get some inspiration for your edge capacities in the middle of the network graph. The answer may surprise you!

One extra hint: your flow is already restricted by the supply out of the source and demand into the sink, so in order to maximize the demand met, how much flow do you want to *allow* from your supply nodes to your demand nodes? Note also that the capacities of your edges don't need to be fully utilized (you can push less flow than allowed).